# employee details along with the max rating in each department

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL to list down employee details such as EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ROLE, DEPARTMENT, and EMP_RATING grouped by dept. Also include the respective employee rating along with the max emp rating for the department.

The `emp_records_table` contains the information of all the employees which are the following features:

```
EMP_ID – ID of the employee
FIRST_NAME – First name of the employee
LAST_NAME – Last name of the employee
GENDER – Gender of the employee
ROLE – Post of the employee
DEPT – Field of the employee
EXP – Years of experience the employee has
COUNTRY – Country in which the employee is presently living
CONTINENT – Continent in which the country is
SALARY – Salary of the employee
EMP_RATING – Performance rating of the employee
MANAGER_ID – The manager under which the employee is assigned 
PROJ_ID – The project on which the employee is working or has worked on
```

i have tried this:

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, role, dept , emp_rating , MAX(emp_rating) AS MAX_EMP_RATING
FROM emp_record_table
GROUP BY dept, emp_id, first_name, last_name, role , emp_rating;
```

[image: query output]

I was expecting to include the respective employee rating along with the max emp rating for the department.

Comment: Since `emp_id` is in the `GROUP BY`, you're getting a max rating for each employee, which is the same as their rating, not grouping the whole department.

Comment: You need a separate subquery to get the max rating grouped just by department.

Comment: You can join the per-user information with this.

Comment: @Barmar could you be more clear?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina its 8.1.0

Comment: If so then use common MAX() OVER ().